# How to select rows that have all values in a collection of IDs

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct, group-concat

The title may not be very descriptive on what I need. I have a table with product_id and store_id columns. I need a way to get all Stores (store_id) that have a collection of product_ids (they need to have ALL products I want). Example:

```
+------------+----------+
| product_id | store_id |
+------------+----------+
|        10  |       1  |
|        20  |       1  |
|        10  |       2  |
|        20  |       2  |
|        30  |       1  |
|        30  |       3  |
|        20  |       3  |
+------------+----------+
```

I want to select all stores that have products 10, 20 and 30 (all of them).
In this example, only store 1 has all 3 products. The other two stores (2 and 3) only have two products, not all 3.

I want to build a query that will return ONLY the store_ids that have all products in stock.
I'm trying something like this, but this is logically not exactly what I need.

```
SELECT st.product_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT st.store_id SEPARATOR ",") 
AS store_ids 
FROM stock_table AS st 
WHERE st.product_id IN (10,20,30) 
GROUP BY st.product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if  the count of product_id is 3

```
SELECT st.product_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT st.store_id SEPARATOR ",") AS store_ids store
FROM stock_table AS st 
WHERE st.product_id IN (10,20,30) 
GROUP BY store
having count(distinct st.product_id) = 3
```

this was the Original answer

```
SELECT st.product_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT st.store_id SEPARATOR ",") store
AS store_ids 
FROM stock_table AS st 
WHERE st.product_id IN (10,20,30) 

GROUP BY store 
having count(distinct product_id) = 3
```

Comment: hello! many thanks for such quick answer... option 1 seems to do the trick! however I also tried option 2 (HAVING COUNT) and here I think I'm missing something... it doesn't seem to work... any clues?

Comment: btw, I think you accidentally deleted your original answer about using AND and not IN

Comment: i have update the answer  with the original answer  too but there is not an AND  .. anyway  check better you data sample  .. the query posted  should return product_id 1  .. or you data sample is different respected  the posted  one ..

Comment: no.. your code does not work I'm afraid.. HOWEVER, if I change the GROUP BY clause, and I use "store_id" instead of product_id as the group by, it seems to work. am I right?